# SESSION variable wont continue to next page

Tags: php, mysql

Even though I have searched and forums I am failing to get a Session Variable to continue to the next page.

Every page has `session_start()`. Each Header has `exit()` after it.

If I add a new member the SESSION Variable is fine. **But** when I log on the SESSION Variable gets **lost** after login.

Here is the code for the Login Page. Everything works except for the SESSION variable wont parse to the next page. What am I missing? <s>oh and the code is a bit messy a bit like my workstation</s>.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    //Connection to DB in the usual way with check to DB

    $myusername = $_POST['myusername'];
    $mypassword = $_POST['mypassword'];

    //hacking protection in the usual way

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE `u_password` = '$mypassword' AND `user` = '$myusername' ";

    $result  = mysqli_query($mdb, $sql);
    $row     = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $count   = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $ls      = "Online";
    $datenow = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $id      = $row['id'];

    $usql = "UPDATE addnewmbr SET loggedstatus = '$ls', logindate = '$datenow'        WHERE id = '$id'";
    if (mysqli_query($mdb, $usql)) {
        $_SESSION["user_id"] = $row['id']; //this variable is lost on next page
        $_SESSION["user"]    = $row['user']; //this variable is lost on next page
        $_SESSION["gender"]  = $row['gender']; //this variable is lost on next page
        if ($_SESSION['gender'] == "man") {
            header('Location: newpage.php');
            exit(); // the redirection $_SESSION['gender'] works so the variable is set
        } else {
            header('Location: anotherpage.php');
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        header('Location: back to indexpage.html');
        exit();
    }
?>
```

**anotherpage.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["user"];
?>
```

**result on this page after Vardump on test page**

```
array(0) { }
```

Comment: Is this the full code?

Comment: Can you show us the "next page"'s code?

Comment: for the login page.... yes except for the db connection and hack protection. The code works except for the variable is lost.

Comment: ok hang fire will show next page

Comment: Create a new page, say `test.php` and just add `var_dump($_SESSION)` and tell what's happening?

Comment: Not every page needs a session start in my pov... Cause that causes to create a new SESSION variable, or am I wrong?

Comment: @J.DKYSR `session_start();` does not create a new session variable, no - it allows you to access the global `$_SESSION`-array. And if you don't have it on all pages, the session might expire in between accessing pages with `session_start()`.

Comment: as you can see the test page shows the variable lost. if I added a new member the Sessions are fine. I have no idea why.

Comment: @MikeIsMad If you do like Praveen Kumar suggested above, in your `anotherpage.php` do `var_dump($_SESSION);` directly after `session_start();` - what does it output? Also, do your logs produce any messages?

Comment: check that the session_id() is the same on both pages

Comment: umm Session_id? So I need to set  a new one with the login? You could be onto something here. Thanks Tom. So would I need to set it to the User id and if this is right wont I need it before the session start?

Comment: The code doesn't appear to be checking whether `mysqli_fetch_array` is returning a row. There's a call to `mysqli_num_rows`, but I don't think that's really necessary. The code can just check whether `mysqli_fetch_array` returned a row or not. I'm also not liking the pattern of referring to `$row` after the subsequent call to `mysqli_query` (to perform the UPDATE). I'd prefer to see the value of `$row['user']` accessed immediately after the fetch, assigning it to another variable. And some kind of verification that it's not empty. (Also, **SQL Injection**.)

Comment: thanx spencer... yes the hack comment was in ref to injection. but thanx though for that. I did have a count in there to check that it connected to the base and picked out the correct id (pword and user) however later in the code I update and this does the same job so I removed the count but left the num rows in (a bit lazy). I have checked the page with echos on the variables and they display. It just gets lost when it heads to a new page. I will investigate Toms suggestion of Session id. I think this could be the culprit and thought that session id was set when session start was invoked.

Comment: Have you just tried to assign something to $_SESSION['foo'], and retrieve that on another page?  Reading the code, what you describe sounds as if you are never assigning any values to the session variables.  Have you turned on mysqli exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from you being vulnerable for SQL injections (preventable by preparing your statements, binding your values and executing it)

Why do you set `$_SESSION["user"]` equal to `$row['user']` and not to `$myusername`?

In this case, they are the same since you fetch the row where `user = $myusername`
Not sure if that solves anything.

Comment: Youre right but even fixing that code duplication does not fix the error. The $_SESSION["user"] will definitely be the mysql  $row['user']

Answer (score 0):

It was an easy fix after all.... For all that get stuck with SESSION variables being lost!

on the header just be careful..... remove the www from the header

e.g. 
SESSION problem 
    header('Location: http://www.website.php');
SESSION fix
    header('Location: http://website.php');

That's all there is to it.